# I2C Address 0x00 not supposed to be showing up

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, i2c

I am currently trying to check all the sensors on my PCB with an I2C scanner to see that they all acknowledge. One of my coworkers had it over the past week and dropped it. When it was given back, there was another I2C address that has shown up on the I2C reader. There shouldn't be another address, given that all of the other sensors already have their own address and did indeed get acknowledged prior to dropping it.

*More specifics on the board*: This is controlled by an ATMEGA328, there is a power management unit (PMIC) with no I2C communication inputs, and 6 basic sensors that communicate with I2C to the ATMEGA328.

Does anyone have any ideas of what this address might be? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using the ATMega328 for scanning the addresses, or something external, like I2C adapter for a PC? Which sensors are they? Sometimes, some devices have multiple addresses that are selectable. Sometimes, there is a bug, and if you leave address selection register to 0x00, it responds to address 0x00 instead of being disabled.

Comment: Are there some DIP switches that might have moved?

Answer (score 2):

Address 0 is a special address named the "general call address." The basic idea is that *any* slave device on the bus can respond to this address. Not all devices actually implement this behavior, though. I've never tried to use it myself. I'm not sure how common it is for slaves to respond to it.

See section 3.1.13 of the I2C specification from NXP:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf

> 3.1.13 General call address
>
> The general call address is for addressing every device connected to the I2C-bus at the same time. However, if a
> device does not need any of the data supplied within the general call
> structure, it can ignore this address by not issuing an
> acknowledgment. If a device does require data from a general call
> address, it acknowledges this address and behave as a slave-receiver.
> The master does not actually know how many devices acknowledged if one
> or more devices respond. The second and following bytes are
> acknowledged by every slave-receiver capable of handling this data. A
> slave who cannot process one of these bytes must ignore it by
> not-acknowledging. Again, if one or more slaves acknowledge, the
> not-acknowledge will not be seen by the master. The meaning of the
> general call address is always specified in the second byte (see
> Figure 16).

I don't know why dropping the scanner would cause this to show up now if it didn't before. Perhaps the scanner has some settings that went back to factory defaults? Is it working as expected otherwise?